# Best way to handle remote storage without local copy

Tags: nas, rsync, storage

I have a directory of data which, until now, has been manually `rsync`d to a Synology based remote storage. The problem is that I don't have enough space anymore on the local drive, so I'd like to find a way to enable a "cloud storage" option. What I'd like to have:

- Do not sync again. I'd like to be able to just point to the remote location.
- Be able to select directories for local storage. Of course, this will require downloading the data.
- I am using both Windows 11 and Linux (Ubuntu). I am fine if the management itself is supported by a single operating system, but that should be accessible in both operating systems (even if only "permanent" data), and manipulation (e.g. deletions) should obviously not corrupt the data.

Comment: Although this is off-topic, best you can do is get a webhosting service, and use FTP and a script that uploads local data, then delete it locally.